# How do I create a function that inserts an element between each pair of elements in a vector

Tags: clojure

I want to write a function that inserts elements between existing elements in a vector. The inserted elements are a function of the elements that precede and succeed it, with the first and last elements remaining unaffected.

E.g. I want inserted elements to be the mean of the elements that precede and succeed it:

Input:

> [1 10 15]

Output:

> [1 5.5 10 12.5 15]

What is the best way to do this in Clojure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
(defn insert-mean-between [xs]
  (let [f (fn [x y]
            [(* (+ x y) 0.5) y])]
    (->> xs
         (partition 2 1)
         (mapcat (partial apply f))
         (cons (first xs))
         vec)))

(insert-mean-between [1 10 15])
;;=> [1 5.5 10 12.5 15]
```

The main *trick* is that `f` is returning the answer and the RHS input. This way later on they will all compose together without repeats. The only problem you will have is that the first element is missing. So we just cons it onto the front. From the outset we had to know that `cons` would be a convenient operation when we chose to be returning the RHS rather than the LHS.

As calculating the mean was just an example, an improved solution would be  for the inserting to be independent of the mean/whatever function:

```
(defn calc-mean [x y] (* (+ x y) 0.5) 
(insert-between calc-mean [1 10 15])
```

Then a more general inserting function might be:

```
(defn insert-between [g xs]
  (->> xs
       (partition 2 1)
       (mapcat (fn [[x y]] [(g x y) y]))
       (cons (first xs))))
```

Comment: If only `partition` had complete transducer variants (arity gets in the way, I suppose), this could make an excellent example of how to use transducers.

Answer (score 4):

and the list of variants won't be complete without the recursive lazy sequence generation:

```
(defn with-avg [[x1 & [x2 :as tail] :as items]]
  (when (seq items)
    (if (seq tail)
      (lazy-cat [x1 (/ (+ x1 x2) 2)] (with-avg tail))
      [x1])))

user> (with-avg [1 2 3 4 5])
;;=> (1 3/2 2 5/2 3 7/2 4 9/2 5)
user> (with-avg [1])
;;=> [1]
user> (with-avg [])
;;=> nil
user> (with-avg [1 2])
;;=> (1 3/2 2)
user> (with-avg [1 2 3])
;;=>(1 3/2 2 5/2 3)
```

Comment: Nice example of nested destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

One way I could solve it is pattern matching `Vector` as `f s t`,  I'm assuming it has 3 elements

Then create variable to assign  first median `first + second / 2` and second median `second + third /2`.

At the end return a new `Vector` with a combination you want.

Example, (*I'm using lein REPL*)

```
user=> (defn insert_medians[vect]
  #_=>    (let [[f s t] vect
  #_=>       m1 (float (/ (+ f s) 2))
  #_=>       m2 (float (/ (+ s t) 2))]
  #_=>       [f m1 s m2 t]))
#'user/insert_medians

user=> (insert_medians [1 10 15])
[1 5.5 10 12.5 15]
```

If a vector is larger than 3 elems, you need to find all the medians first and then insert into the original vector using [`interleave`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/interleave#example-542692ccc026201cdc326c4c) fn.

Comment: Unfortunately the length of the vector isn't consistent. Some vectors have > 1000 elements

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn insert-between
  "Inserts elements between existing elements in a vector v. The inserted
  elements are a result of applying the function f to the elements that precede
  and succeed it, with the first and last elements of v remaining unaffected."
  [f [x & xs :as v]]
  (->> (partition 2 1 v)
       (mapcat (fn [[a b]] [(f a b) b]))
       (cons x)
       (into [])))

(defn mean [& numbers]
  (float (/ (apply + numbers) (count numbers))))

(insert-between mean [1 10 15])    ; => [1 5.5 10 10 12.5 15]
(insert-between + [1 10 15 20 25]) ; => [1 11 10 25 15 35 20 45 25]
(insert-between mean [])           ; => [nil] :(
```